# How to add a subview with drag in animation from top of the view, in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-animation

I need to add a `UIDatePicker` subview on a button click to my main view.
How can I add the view with animation such that the subview flips in from the top of the main view and on removing ,undergoes the reverse animation ? I know the subview can be added in a frame that is outside the visible area of the view and then moving it to visible area using `CABasicAnimation` will be abetter choice. So need help regarding the animation block that I should use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: refer this tutorial it used to make basic animation in ios [UIView Animation Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this bellow code... here if yourView default frame with origin y = -500 then try bellow code on any `UIButton` click event..   also set frame which you want

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    CGRect frame = yourView.frame;
    frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y + 500; // give any value for display yourView
    yourView.frame = frame;
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:yourView cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `CATransaction` for animation.